# Extjs 3.2. Grid View-Store correlation

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, view, store

In my example the order of recording data in the grid is as follows:

1. Add needed amount of empty records
2. Change value in needed cells

This is necessary in order to transmit only the changes from the server either entire table.
In some cases there may be no changes or some data may even be removed. But the main idea that data must change in two steps.
The problem is that the rewriting of data can occur at different times over call rendering.
In some cases we will have errors.

```
//error
store.insert(0, new Rec());   
win.show();         
store.insert(0, new Rec());

//no error
store.insert(0, new Rec());     
store.insert(0, new Rec());  
win.show();         

//no error
win.show();         
store.insert(0, new Rec());   
store.insert(0, new Rec());
```

We can't guarantee the order of execution insert and show functions, because they can be called from different asynchronous requests.

**My question is in the next;**
Why are changes in store depends on the view state and how can we protect ourself from this?

[test case](http://pastehtml.com/view/bva5t80mf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can refresh the GridView after show

```
win.show();
grid.getView().refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the GridView's  listener for the store's "add" event isn't added to the view until the GridView's init() (this is called from Grid's `onRender()`) is called.  This happens when the grid is rendered (win.show()).  You weren't getting an error on #2 (insert-insert-show) because it never hit the `Ext.fly(rows[0]).addClass(this.firstRowCls);` in the GridView's `processRows()`.

I changed the code a bit to print out some logging in the GridViews init and onAdd(handler for store's add event):

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        columns: [{
                dataIndex: 'common',
                editor: new Ext.form.TextField({allowBlank: false})
            }]
    });

    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            record: 'plant',
            fields: [{name: 'common', type: 'string'}]
        })
    });

    var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        store: store,
        cm: cm,
        region: "center",
        view: new Ext.grid.GridView({
            init : function(grid) {
                console.log("\tinit()");
                this.grid = grid;

                this.initTemplates();
                this.initData(grid.store, grid.colModel);
                this.initUI(grid);
            },
            onAdd : function(store, records, index) {
                console.log("\t\tadding: ", records[0].id);
                this.insertRows(store, index, index + (records.length-1));
            }
        })
    });

    var win = new Ext.Window({
        layout: "border",
        items: [grid],
        width : 300,
        height : 300
    });

    var Rec = grid.getStore().recordType;
  /*   
    console.log("show-insert-insert");
    win.show();

    console.log("\t1st insert");
    store.insert(0, new Rec());

    console.log("\t2nd insert");
    store.insert(0, new Rec());     
   */
    console.log("insert-insert-show");
    console.log("\t1st insert");
    store.insert(0, new Rec());

    console.log("\t2nd insert");
    store.insert(0, new Rec());

    console.log("win.show()");
    win.show();
});
```

Here is the console from the three different cases:

```
show-insert-insert
    init()
    1st insert
        adding: ext-record-1
    2nd insert
        adding: ext-record-2
    win.show()

insert-show-insert
    1st insert
    win.show()
    init()
    2nd insert
        adding: ext-record-2

Ext.fly(rows[0]) is null
[Break On This Error]   
Ext.fly(rows[0]).addClass(this.firstRowCls);
ext-all-debug.js (line 43959

insert-insert-show
    1st insert
    2nd insert
    win.show()
    init()
```

As you can see the only case where it actually adds both items to the Grid (and GridView) is on the show-insert-insert case.  Best solution I've found so far is to just do

```
win.show();
win.hide();
```

at the beginning.  I haven't found any better solution so far.  I hope this helps.